# por que el PDF no tiene formato al convertir de Docx a PDF? Framework Laravel (DomPDF PhpWord)

Tags: laravel-5, dompdf, phpword

Este es el codigo que estoy ocupando en Laravel

**ArchivoWordController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
include(base_path().'/vendor/autoload.php');

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class ArchivoWordController extends Controller
{

    public function crearWordDocx(){

      $data = DB::table('materials')
         ->orderBy('folio', 'desc')
         ->get();

      $contador = count($data);

      $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor(Storage_path('plantilla.docx'));



       $templateProcessor->cloneRow('first_name', $contador);
       $i = 1;

       foreach($data as $row)
       {
        $concatenar = "first_name#".$i;
        $templateProcessor->setValue($concatenar, $row->folio);
        $i++;
       }



      $nombre = "Roberto";

      $templateProcessor->setValue('nombre_empresa',$nombre);

      $templateProcessor->saveAs('Documento02.docx');

      $domPdfPath = realpath('../vendor/dompdf/dompdf');
      \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('DomPDF');
      \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath($domPdfPath);

       $phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load('Documento02.docx');

       $pdfWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'PDF');

       $pdfWriter->save('result.pdf');


  }

}
```

Ocupo la plantilla que se le añaden valores, eso si lo hace bien, pero al momento de convertir el Word generado con los valores a PDF que no contiene formato, Por favor me pueden decir que estoy realizando mal?

Word ya con los valores añadidos a la plantilla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este el PDF que me genera pero no tiene formato

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

La conversión a pdf desde PHPword a DOMPD|FPDF|TCPDF o cualquier otro no procesa estilos ni imágenes, desde phpword aún o hay solución para esto.

Una solución temporal es usar [ConvertApi](https://packagist.org/packages/convertapi/convertapi-php), envias el documento en doc y este lo retorna convertido al formato que le especifiques.